# Horizontal lines in Chrome Developer Tools while scrolling

Tags: google-chrome

Anyone seeing colorful horizontal lines  when scrolling in chrome developer tools?

I posted more info and a screenshot to the [Chrome Product Form here](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!search/horizontal%2420lines%2420chrome%2420scroll%2420linux/chrome/TGb6XNtaUWw/ycNQ6PziKWAJ) a while back but posting here as well in case this looks familiar.

Is it a video card issue? The lines don't happen in any other app (Firefox in various modes, ...).

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on a way to get around this, though a destructive one.

I deleted my chrome config folder (`~/.config/google-chrome-beta/` in my case, it's somewhere in ~/.config) and the lines went away.

Obviously ***be warned*** that this means  passwords, configurations,extensions are forgotten! So don't try this before having these listed/backed up.